# convert mongodb data to gridview

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-web-api, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

how to show the table in  gridview? the datas are retrived from mongodb and this particular table consists of multiple tables inside some fields.

```
var collection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("ABC");            
var query = collection.AsQueryable().Take(10).ToList();   
IEnumerable<BsonDocument> allUsers = 
BsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<BsonDocument>>(query);-----//shows cant convert collection.generic.list to bsondocument.
```

or  i tried this too..

```
var collection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("ABC");          
var query = collection.AsQueryable().Take(10).ToList();  
DataTable dt = (DataTable)MongoDB.Bson.IO.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(query, (typeof(DataTable))); ---//jsonconvert doesnot have deserializeobject
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing someting wrong trying to deserialize an IList to Json, you can serialize the list to a JSON, or vice versa. You already have a List of object so you don't need to do the deserialization. 
You can try and build your DataTable using the this list

> "var query = collection.AsQueryable().Take(10).ToList();"

The construction of Datatable will look someting like this;

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("Column1");
dt.Columns.Add("Column2");
dt.Columns.Add("Column3");
foreach (var item in query)
{
    var row = dt.NewRow();

    row["Column1"] = item.Column1;
    row["Column2"] = item.Column2;
    row["Column3"] = item.Column3;

    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}

return dt;
```

Comment: I just simply want to show the table from a database. is there any other way to show the data in grid view without any declaration property? because still **var** **query** my code runs perfectly and it retrieved the data from database. i just need to show that in grid view (my final step).

Comment: This is the only way I know you can do it.